# Changing value based on another value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames

`df1`:

```
col1_a col2_a
MAR1 R1
MAR2 R2
MAR3 R3
```

`df2`:

```
col1_b col2_b
MAR1 R1
MAR2 R20
MAR3
MAR4 R4
MAR5 R5
```

and I want

```
col1_b col2_b
MAR1 R1
MAR2 R2
MAR3 R3
MAR4 R4
MAR5 R5
```

So in the case **col1_a == col1_b**, I want to **replace col2_b with col2_a**

Unfortunately, I do not have a solution that works. Can anyone help?

Comment: set_index & map or merge

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1_a':['MAR1','MAR2','MAR3'], 'col2_a':['R1', 'R2', 'R3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1_b':['MAR1','MAR2','MAR3', 'MAR4', 'MAR5'], 'col2_b':['R1', 'R20', None, 'R4', 'R5']})
```

Then you can achieve this with:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', left_on='col1_b', right_on='col1_a')
selection_condition = pd.isna(df3["col2_a"])
df3["col2_a"].iloc[selection_condition] = df3[selection_condition]["col2_b"]
```

And

```
df3[["col1_b", "col2_a"]]
```

will have your desired columns.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to do it using dictionary

```
# create a dictionary from df1
d=dict(df1.values )

#using mask update the values in col2_b where mapping returns a non-null value
df2['col2_b']= df2['col2_b'].mask(df2['col1_b'].map(d).notna(), 
        df2['col1_b'].map(d))
df2
```

```
col1_b  col2_b
0   MAR1    R1
1   MAR2    R2
2   MAR3    R3
3   MAR4    R4
4   MAR5    R5
```